# Utilizar fichero .kv

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Estoy intentando hacer un hola mundo muy básico. Entonces en el archivo principal .py, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class HelloApp (App):
    pass

HelloApp().run()
```

Luego, tengo el archivo hello.kv aparte de la siguiente manera

```
Label:
    text: "Hello World"
```

Pero me devuelve como error

```
Invalid data after declaration
```

Previamente realice todas las instalaciones de Kivy, de hecho en la clase HelloApp (App), tenia el codigo para levantar una pantalla con el mesaje "Hello World" y me funcionaba, pero cuando quiero hacerlo desde el archivo hello, falla, si alguien pudiera darme una mano...muchas gracias...

Comment: hola, por favor añade cómo lees el archivo kv, imagino que hay algún problema de encoding, pero no se puede estar seguro si no tenemos todo el código. También ayudaría que pegues todo el error (si es que no está completo)

Comment: Miralo aqui igual te puede servir. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189175/kv-file-invalid-data-after-declaration